# debugging Silverlight WCF RIA app; "Load operation failed for query 'GetTblProjects'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound."

Tags: wcf, silverlight

Presently I am building a Silverlight WCF RIA application.  It has been going well, with the client obtaining the data it needs without a problem.  Then I decided to add a table to the database, update the associated Entity Data Model EDMX file, and re-generated the associated Domain Service class.  Now it still gets all the tables it used to get with no problem, but when I try to obtain data from the new table tblProject, I'm receiving this error:

```
Error
Load operation failed for query 'GetTblProjects'.  The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

Error Details
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult    asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<Load>b__17(Object )
Caused by: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient`1.EndQueryCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
Caused by: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
Caused by: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
```

I've spent a lot of time looking at the domain service class, along with the XAML code and the associated view model class, and can't see any differences between the implementation related to, say, the tblBasin database table that works fine with no problems and the new tblProject table that is giving me the error.  When I turn on WCF tracing, here is what I get for the tblBasin:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>458758</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-04-20T21:54:03.3280726Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{169c9eeb-338f-4ea5-a93a-34f234113283}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="5276" ThreadID="14" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>WKSTCAL0123</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord"     Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityImpersonationSuccess.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Security Impersonation succeeded at the server.</Description>
          <AppDomain>f8f8d82-2-129794323085920534</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/SecurityImpersonationTraceRecord">
            <OperationAction>http://tempuri.org/ProjectSetDomainServicebinary/GetTblBasins</OperationAction>
            <OperationName>GetTblBasins</OperationName>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Here is what I get for the tblProject table data that fails:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>262163</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-04-20T21:54:03.3270721Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{30c0de8a-fd38-4ca6-8c8a-b88f27a783bf}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="5276" ThreadID="12" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>WKSTCAL0123</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en- CA/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageReceived.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Received a message over a channel.</Description>
          <AppDomain>f8f8d82-2-129794323085920534</AppDomain>
          <Source>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext+HostedHttpInput/61784148</Source>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTransmitTraceRecord">
           <MessageProperties>
              <AllowOutputBatching>False</AllowOutputBatching>
              <Via>http://localhost:57671/Services/ZEGApps-Web-Services-ProjectSetDomainService.svc/binary/GetTblProjects</Via>
            </MessageProperties>
            <MessageHeaders>
              <To d4p1:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:57671/Serv ices/ZEGApps-Web-Services-ProjectSetDomainService.svc/binary/GetTblProjects</To>
            </MessageHeaders>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
   </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?  TIA.

UPDATE: All service calls are succeeding except the call to obtain data from the new tblProject database table I created.

Comment: Are all your service calls failing or only the one with the newly created entity domain object ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds pretty basic, but your question doesn't mention this information and the problem sounds very much like this could be your answer:

Have you updated the appropriate executable files on the server?  If you updated only the client code with the knowledge of the new table, the server would behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your reply, John!

Presently, the application is in pretty early development stages, so I am actually testing it using the Visual Studio Cassini web server.  Both the client and the server projects are in the same solution.  So when I rebuild the application, it should rebuild the associated XAP file, shouldn't it?  This is what the timestamp for the file indicates.  BTW, the SQL Server database is running on a separate database server.

Also, when I open and inspect the EDMX file, it shows the tblProject table as I expect.

If there is anything else I may have missed or you have any other suggestions, they are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

(Don't know if this still an open question...)
Have you tried using Fiddler and making your remote call ? Sometimes an error occurs on the server and an error page is returned to the client. As RIA Services handles the call, you just get a generic error message.

If your dev server is on localhost, please remember to use "localhost." (with the point) to have the call intercepted by Fiddler.